# Retrieving the text input's value which was stored into localStorage

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage

I am trying to parse JSON data from the url (only feeds data from the JSON) and stored the values in localstorage now I am trying to retrieve the values that are stored in the localstorage from one file to another file the stored values is in the from of array objects.while retrieving I am getting only the final object in other file. Can anyone help me how to retrieve all the objects? I am attaching the code below new.html (here I am trying to store the data in localstorage) and new1.html (here I am retrieving the data). Thank you

new.html:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width ,height=device-height"/>

</head>

<body>
    <div id="header">
        <h1> Login </h1>
    </div>

    <div id="section">
    <!--script type="text/javascript" 
    charset="utf-8" src="cordova-1.7.0.js"></script-->
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#submit").click(insertId);
        });

        function insertId() {
            // Getting the value of your text input
            var did = document.getElementById("deviceId").value;

            if (did == null || did == "") {

                alert("Kindly enter a valid Device ID");
                return false;

            }   else    {


                console.log("id: ", did);
            }

            window.alert("DID entered is : " + did);
            window.open("new1.html");

                            $.ajax({
                                    url : "https://api.thingspeak.com/channels/9/feeds.json?results=10",
                                    dataType:"json",
                                    cache: false,
                                    error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
                                    debugger;
                                            alert(xhr.statusText);
                                            alert(thrownError);
                                        },
                                    success : function(json1) {
                                    console.log(json1);

                                    json1.feeds.forEach(function(feed, i) {

                                      console.log("\n The deails of " + i + "th Object are :  \nCreated_at: " + feed.created_at + "\nEntry_id:" + feed.entry_id + "\nField1:" + feed.field1 + "\nField2:" + feed.field2);

                                            localStorage.setItem('Created_at', feed.created_at);
                                            var create = localStorage.getItem('Created_at');
                                            console.log(create);
                                            localStorage.setItem('Entry_id', feed.entry_id);
                                            var entry = localStorage.getItem('Entry_id');
                                            console.log(entry);
                                            localStorage.setItem('Field1', feed.field1);
                                            var fd1 = localStorage.getItem('Field1');
                                            console.log(fd1);
                                            localStorage.setItem('Field2', feed.field2);
                                            var fd2 = localStorage.getItem('Field2');
                                            console.log(fd2);
                                    });
                                    }
                                    });

        return false;
    }

    </script>

    <form id="insertId">
          <br><input type="text" placeholder="DeviceId" id="deviceId" /><br>
          <br>
          <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
    </div>
</body>
```

new1.html:

```
<html>

<body onload="init();">
    <div id="header">
        <h1> USER DETAILS </h1>
    </div>

    <div id="section">

        <script>

            // Called on body's `onload` event
            function init() {
                // Retrieving the text input's value which was stored into localStorage

                var create = localStorage.getItem('Created_at');
                console.log(create);
                document.writeln("<br>Created_at  = "+create);
                var entry = localStorage.getItem('Entry_id');
                document.writeln("<br>Entry_id  = "+entry);
                var fd1 = localStorage.getItem('Field1');
                document.writeln("<br>Field1  = "+fd1);
                var fd2 = localStorage.getItem('Field2');
                document.writeln("<br>Field3  = "+fd2);



            }
        </script>

        <body onload="init();">

        </body>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: did you check in your browser local storage if you really store all of your data there?

Comment: You have the only one record in your json (feeds.json)

Comment: Yes.I have stored all the data i have checked it in the consolelog@pryxen

Comment: No.I have 10 records in json (feeds.json) https://api.thingspeak.com/channels/9/feeds.json?results=10  you can have a look in the url @NitinDhomse